MoveIt move_group_interface not using sim time
I'm trying to get the pose of the end-affector using auto pose = move_group_interface.getCurrentPose("tool");. I encounter the following error:
[moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds. Requested time 1712569460.725784, but latest received state has time 1447.635000.
Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[ERROR] [1712569461.725921575] [move_group_interface]: Failed to fetch current robot state

This looks to me like the move_group_interface is unaware of the time used by other ros-nodes. Anyone any ideas on how to get this working?
Here is a more complete version of the code:
Gp25Services::Gp25Services(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> move_group_interface_node)
: Node("gp25_services"),
move_group_interface(move_group_interface_node, "manipulator")
{
    // Create the current_pose service
    this->current_pose_service_ = this->create_service<reconstruction_msgs::srv::CurrentPose>(
        "/gp25/current_pose",
        std::bind(&Gp25Services::current_pose_handle_request, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}


void Gp25Services::current_pose_handle_request(
    const std::shared_ptr<reconstruction_msgs::srv::CurrentPose::Request> request,
    const std::shared_ptr<reconstruction_msgs::srv::CurrentPose::Response> response)
{
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Received request for current pose");
    (void)request;

    auto pose = move_group_interface.getCurrentPose("tool");
    response->pose = pose;
}

Which is used by ros here:
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto move_group_interface_node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("gp25_services_move_group_interface_node");
    rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor executor;
    executor.add_node(move_group_interface_node);
    auto spinner = std::thread([&executor]() { executor.spin(); });

    auto node = std::make_shared<Gp25Services>(move_group_interface_node);
    rclcpp::spin(node);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
}

I find the way I'm passed a second ros-node to a class which is of itself a ros-node quite strange, but the move_group_interface requires its own node and I would like to keep all other robot related actions and services in a single class.

It seems that one node is using system time: Requested time 1712569460.725784 [move_group],
and that one node is using simulated time: but latest received state has time 1447.635000. [joint_state_publisher]
So you can probably solve your issue by adding use_sim_time parameter to true in the launch files of both nodes.
In my case, this approach made times so close, however, I'm still not able to fetch the pose, and I'm also seeking solutions for that.

I've managed to fix similar problem by following this link.
It has something to do with properly initializing executors, threads and propagating node options. Simply following this link helped me to solve similar if not the same issue!
